# What is the best regression approach for my case?

Tags: regression

I have set of data Columns say $A,B$

Now I form a new data Columns

$Y= A+B$

Now $Y$ is the dependent

I have another independent data $X$

I now need to fit a regression of the form

$Y=c*X^b$

where $c$ and $b$ are constant to be predicted from regression

Now I used power fit to find $c$ and $b$

To get a good $R^2$, $AdjR^2$ , $P(>\mid t \mid) <0.06$ and
$cooks~Distance<0.16$ I took less than 0.16 as the conditions to be checked if the model is good

Until now

if I get $YPred$ as the $Y$ predicted values.

As I know $A$ and $B$ values

Now by doing $A= YPred - B$

To get $Apred$ to be very close to the actual $A$
That is if I perform a regression of $A$ vs $Apred$ then by I look to get $R^2$, $AdjR^2$ , $P(>\mid t \mid) <0.06$ and $cooks~Distance<0.16$

Kind help with the best way to approach

If my method of approach

Someone can guide me in this

Actually what I have is

$A=c*X^b+d*B$

Now i need find a suitable value of $c,b$ and $d$ using regression here

I really don't know how to approach

I assumed $d=-1$

And tried the above

Please someone help I will be helpful to me

Comment: Your formatting could be significantly improved; as it is, this is very hard to read.  Please use Mathjax to format the math as well.